# Drawing lines with sleep command lagging

Tags: java, graphics, drawing, line

My objective is to get this kind of result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdMvZ.png)

the grey line being the path the mouse follows and the black line the lines you see on the screen, but im having two issues

1. The line previous to the new line disapears (i want it to stay)
2. The Line draw is laggy and only draws when my mouse is static

   public class Press extends Applet implements MouseMotionListener {

   ```
   public int count;
   public int x1, y1, x2, y2;

   public void init(){
       this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
   }

   public Press(){
       count = 0;
   }

   public void paint (Graphics g) {
       Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
       g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(x1, y1, x2, y2));
       repaint();
   }

       public void clickup(){
       count++;
       }

       public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
       x1 = x2;
       y1 = y2;
       x2 = e.getX();
       y2 = e.getY();
       System.out.println("x: " + x2 + " y: " + y2 + " Count: " + count);
       clickup();
       try {
           Thread.sleep(100);
       } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
           e1.printStackTrace();
       }

       }

       public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
       }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Press mouse = new Press();
       }
   ```

   }

Comment: 1- Don't use `Thread.sleep` inside the Event Dispatching Thread; 2- Add the points you want to draw to some kind of `List` and each time `paint` is called, repaint all the points in the `List`

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to use a (Buffered)Image, to draw the Image in paint, and to draw on the Image in your mouse event handlers. [Here is an example](http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/ex/PaintArea.java)